# Question re: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{2}{2n+1}^+}x^2\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

Let $f(x):=x^2\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right|$ for all $x\ne0$. Let $x_n:=\frac{2}{2n+1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The author claims that

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  x_n^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_n)}{x-x_n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  x_n^+}\frac{x^2\cos(\pi/x)}{x-x_n};$$
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  x_n^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_n)}{x-x_n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  x_n^+}\frac{-x^2\cos(\pi/x)}{x-x_n}.$$

I am not clear about the reasoning underlying the removal of the absolute value. Why can we assume $\cos(\pi/x)\geq0$ in first equality and $\cos(\pi/x)<0$ in the second?

In the first equality, this means that for a $\delta>0$, for all $x\in(x_n,x_n+\delta)$, $\cos(\pi /x)\geq0$. What assumption is sufficient on $\delta$ in order to ensure that $\cos(\pi/x)\geq0$?

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi/x_n) =0$, so the $\cos(\pi/x)$ changes sign at $x_n$. Think about what this means.

Comment: For $x$ near $(2n+1)\pi /2$, $\cos x$ is positive if $x$ is to the left of  $(2n+1)\pi /2$ and negative to the right of this point.

Comment: @Gary, Correct but couldn't it be positive before $\pi/x_n$ and negative after $\pi/x_n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there a way to deduce this? I mean without using the graph to justify it. If $x<\frac{2}{2n+1}$, then $\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi<\frac{\pi}{x}$. What should be the next step?

Comment: Look at the derivative. You just have to decide whether it is increasing or decreasing through $x_n$.

Comment: @Gary sorry I'm not sure I follow. For example if $\pi/2<\pi/x<3\pi/2$, then $\cos(\pi/x)<0$. So I don't see how the change of sign will always be from negative to positive. So it seems like $\pi/x$ has to also be bounded from above? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You are indeed correct.